# Xcode 6 simulator not deleting sandbox

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Without going on a bizarre snipe hunt into the bowels of ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator, I can't seem to remove an app completely from Xcode 6's simulator.

If I run the app the first time, all is good - The app believes it is the first time launched.
(no NSUserDefaults, etc)

If I then tap/hold to delete the app in the simulator, then re-run, all the data is there again-

Ergo it's NOT a clean install launch at this point.

Anyone figure out how to *really* remove the app from the simulator, as it is not removed as cleanly as it is on the device..

Comment: Do u rerun it with a different sdk version?

Comment: Definitely sounds like a bug. Try the Xcode 6.1 betas: judging from what's being posted to devforums.apple.com, the 6.0 Simulator is mega-busted.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems like a bug in the latest simulator. Currently I've only been successful with the "Reset Content and Settings..." item from the "iOS Simulator" drop down menu.

Comment: Unfortunately, that also nukes all photos added to the simulator, along with all contacts. **HIGHLY** undesirable. I just want the app's data gone.